# D3 Traversing Internal JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am new to D3 which means I am a little unclear about how complicated datasets like JSON are handled, usually when I am traversing JSON I use a bunch of nested `for` loops and things like that, things that D3 seems to take care of for me.

I was following a tutorial on data-binding in D3, and came up with this:

```
 var dataset = [{
  "bread": "Honey Bread",
  "ingredients": [{
    "ingredient": "Whole Wheat Flour",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Water",
    "quantity": 1
  }, , {
    "ingredient": "Honey",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Yeast",
    "quantity": 1
  }, , {
    "ingredient": "Salt",
    "quantity": 1
  }]
}, {
  "bread": "Grain Bread",
  "ingredients": [{
    "ingredient": "Freshly Milled Whole Wheat Flour",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Water",
    "quantity": 1
  }, , {
    "ingredient": "Honey",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Yeast",
    "quantity": 1
  }, , {
    "ingredient": "Salt",
    "quantity": 1
  }]
}]
var svg = d3.select(".images")
  .append("svg")

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle");

circles.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return (i * 50) + 25;
  })
  .attr("cy", function() {
    return 25;
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    console.log(d);

    for (var i = 0; i < d.ingredients.length; i++) {
      return d.ingredients[i].quantity;
    }
  })
```

It works fine, my problem is on the final `return` which means that it gets to the first object node and exits the loop, assigning only one (`1`) quantity.

So how can I do this so that I get a circle for each ingredient? Do I use a different method or is my code simply in need of a tweak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using the top most level in your dataset you can create 2 `<g>` elements.

```
var breads = svg.selectAll(".bread")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bread");
```

Since the top most level has two elements, the code above will create two `<g>` elements.

Then, you can use the `bread` elements to create the nested ingredients:

```
// For each bread get the ingredients, then bind
// and create a circle element for each associated ingredient
var ingredients = breads.selectAll(".ingredients")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.ingredients;
  })
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "ingredient");
```

Full working example:

```js
var dataset = [{
  "bread": "Honey Bread",
  "ingredients": [{
    "ingredient": "Whole Wheat Flour",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Water",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Honey",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Yeast",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Salt",
    "quantity": 1
  }]
}, {
  "bread": "Grain Bread",
  "ingredients": [{
    "ingredient": "Freshly Milled Whole Wheat Flour",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Water",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Honey",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Yeast",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "ingredient": "Salt",
    "quantity": 1
  }]
}];

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var breads = svg.selectAll(".bread")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 100 + ")";
  })
  .attr("class", "bread");

// Draw the circles
var ingredients = breads.selectAll(".ingredients")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.ingredients;
  })
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "ingredient")
  .attr("r", 40)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 2 * 40 * (i + 1);
  })
  .attr("cy", 100);

// Add the ingredient label
var labels = breads.selectAll(".label")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.ingredients;
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return 2 * 40 * (i + 1);
  })
  .attr("y", 100)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.ingredient;
  });
```

```css
.ingredient {
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
.label {
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <svg height="300" width="800"></svg>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/4t27r4fn/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Since your dataset variable contains two objects (each a type of bread with ingredients), and since you're binding "dataset" to "circles," you're only going to get two circles (one for each bread).

If you want the radius to be a function of the number of ingredients (which it sort of looked like you were going for), you just need to return d.ingredients.length in your radius function.

If you want a circle for each ingredient, you would need to bind the ingredients to "circles" rather than the parent bread objects. One way to do this would be create an array of ingredient objects that have an attribute for what kind of bread they're in: var ingredients = [{name: honey, quantity: 5, bread: Honey Bread}, ...]. If you bind this to circles, you'll get a circle for every ingredient, and you could choose a color for the circle based on the type of bread, for example, if you are trying to show multiple bread recipes at a time.

Comment: Could you provide some example code for the last scenario? That is what I am going for, a circle for each ingredient where they are bound to circles not the parent bread objects.